# Simple check in shared memory return SIGSEGV error 008b

Tags: c, fork, shared-memory, child-process, segmentation-fault

I implemented in C a shared memory to let forked child comunicate eachother, here's a Minimal, Complete, and Verificable example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

#define SHMEMORY

#define NUM_SEMS 2

#define LOCK                    \
    sops.sem_num = 1;           \
    sops.sem_op = -1;           \
    semop(sem_Id, &sops, 1);
#define UNLOCK                  \
    sops.sem_num = 1;           \
    sops.sem_op = 1;            \
    semop(sem_Id, &sops, 1);
#define TEST_ERROR    if (errno) {dprintf(STDERR_FILENO,        \
                      "%s:%d: PID=%5d: Error %d (%s)\n", \
                      __FILE__,         \
                      __LINE__,         \
                      getpid(),         \
                      errno,            \
                      strerror(errno));}

#define POP_SIZE 100 //number of child
#define TRUE 1

struct shared_data {
    /* index where next write will happen */
    unsigned long cur_idx;

    int invite_sent[POP_SIZE][POP_SIZE];
};

static void init();
static int invite_sent_check(int stud);
int maxMin_rand(int max,int min);
void handle_signal(int sig);

int sim_time = 10;

unsigned long next_num;
struct sembuf sops;
pid_t *kid_pids;
int mem_Id, sem_Id;

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int status, cur_i;
    struct shared_data* corso;
    pid_t child_pid, my_pid;

    int stud = 0;
    int exit_loop = 0;

/*********************************************************/
    struct sigaction sa;
    sigset_t  my_mask;

    /* handler  SIGALRM
     */
    sa.sa_handler = handle_signal;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&my_mask);

    sa.sa_mask = my_mask;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);
/**********************************************************/
    mem_Id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(*corso), 0600);
    TEST_ERROR;

    /* Attach the shared memory to a pointer */
    corso = shmat(mem_Id, NULL, 0);
    TEST_ERROR;

    corso->cur_idx = 0;   /* init first counter */

/*********************************************************/
    sem_Id = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, NUM_SEMS, 0600);
    TEST_ERROR;
    /* Sem 0 to syncronize the start of child processes */
    semctl(sem_Id, 0, SETVAL, 0);

#ifdef SHMEMORY
    semctl(sem_Id, 1, SETVAL, 1);
#endif  
    TEST_ERROR;

    sops.sem_num = 0;     /* check the 0-th semaphore */
    sops.sem_flg = 0;     /* no flag */

init();


    kid_pids = malloc(POP_SIZE*sizeof(*kid_pids));
    for (i = 0; i < POP_SIZE; i++) {

        switch (kid_pids[i] = fork()) {

        case -1:
            /* Handle error */
            TEST_ERROR;
            break;

        case 0:
            /* Wait for the green light */
            sops.sem_op = -1;
            semop(sem_Id, &sops, 1);

            while(exit_loop==0 || exit_loop==1){

                LOCK;

                if(exit_loop == 0){ 
                    stud = corso->cur_idx;
                    printf("%d %d\n",stud,getpid());
                    corso->cur_idx++;
                    exit_loop = 1;
                }

                if(invite_sent_check(stud) == 1){

                }


                UNLOCK;
                }

            exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    alarm(sim_time);

    while (shmctl(mem_Id, IPC_RMID, NULL)) { TEST_ERROR; }

    sops.sem_op = POP_SIZE;
    semop(sem_Id, &sops, 1);

    /* Waiting for all child POP_SIZEesses to terminate */
    while ((child_pid = wait(&status)) != -1) {
        dprintf(2,"PID=%d. Sender (PID=%d) terminated with status 0x%04X\n",
            getpid(),
            child_pid,
            status);
    }

    /* Now the semaphore may be deallocated */
    semctl(sem_Id, 0, IPC_RMID);

    exit(0);
}

static void init(){
printf("INIT\n");

struct shared_data * corso;
corso = shmat(mem_Id, NULL, 0);
corso->cur_idx=0; 

int r, q, j;


    j = 0;
    q = 0;
    while(j < POP_SIZE){
        q = 0;
        while(q < POP_SIZE){ 
            corso->invite_sent[j][q] = -1; 
            q++;
        }
        j++;
    }
}

int maxMin_rand(int max, int min){      
          int reset;
          int randomics=12345;
          int w=0;
          while(w<reset) {
            randomics++; 
            w++;   
          }  
          next_num = next_num+randomics;
          next_num = next_num*1103515245 +12345;
          unsigned int result=(unsigned int) ((next_num*65536)%(max+1))+min;

          int reload;
          w=0;
          while(w<reload) {  
          next_num++; 
          w++; 
          }
          return result;
}

static int invite_sent_check(int stud){ 
    struct shared_data * corso;
    corso = shmat(mem_Id, NULL, 0);

    int i = 0;
    int q = 0;
    while(i < POP_SIZE){
        if(i == stud){
            q = 0;
            while(q < POP_SIZE){
                if(corso->invite_sent[i][q] != -1){
                    return 1;
                }
                q++;
            }

        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
void handle_signal(int signal){

    int child_pid;
    int status;
    struct shared_data * corso;
    corso = shmat(mem_Id, NULL, 0);

    switch (signal) {
        case SIGALRM:

    for(int i = 0; i < POP_SIZE; i++){
        kill(kid_pids[i], SIGKILL);
    }

    while (shmctl(mem_Id, IPC_RMID, NULL)) { 
        TEST_ERROR; 
    }


    while ((child_pid = wait(&status)) != -1) {
        dprintf(2,"PID=%d. Sender (PID=%d) terminated with status 0x%04X\n",
            getpid(),
            child_pid,
            status);
    }

    semctl(sem_Id, 0, IPC_RMID);

    exit(0);
    break;
    }   
}
```

The forked children keep LOCK and UNLOCK as long as the timer goes (sim_time = 10). Then the SIGNAL_HANDLER kills all the children, and terminate.
I keep getting a SIGSEGV error from a RANDOM child that terminate with status 008B and stops his "brothers" until the handler kills all the other processes. As long as I know, this error concern pointer in the shared memory, is that right? Or I'm missing/I wrote something really wrong? Even this little method that checks if in the INVITE_SENT matrix, at least 1 value is different from -1 cause a crash, instead of just returning 0.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I see that you've made an effort to present excerpts of your code that convey the essentials, but that's rarely possible to do reliably when you're chasing a problem you don't understand well already.  What we look for is a [mcve] -- a small, self-contained example that demonstrates the issue.  Sometimes it can work to build such a thing from excerpts of the original code, but other times it's easier to build it from scratch.  In any case, what you've presented is well short of an MCVE, being missing many details that could be relevant.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Edited the original code like you asked

Comment: No, I most definitely **did not** ask for the whole original code.  Since my necessarily brief comment did not convey the idea effectively, please follow the hyperlink I provided to get a fuller explanation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger There it is

Comment: I could work with that, if only it reproduced the error for me.  Does it do so for you?  I appreciate that this may all be a bit frustrating for you, but please understand that the process of creating an MCVE is no mere hurdle or formality, but rather a *bona fide* debugging technique in its own right.  It stands a good chance of helping you discover the error yourself, and if you don't discover it that way then it cuts down the work that we at SO must do to a level that is reasonable to ask us to undertake.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Everytime I run the code, during the childer "time to do stuff" one of them crashes. In my cmd, I read "PID=(father PID). Sender (PID=(Child_crashedPID) terminated with status (0x008B)\n". When the timer goes off, I read POP_SIZE -1 print of "PID=(father PID). Sender (PID=(ChildPID) terminated with status (0x009)\n" that is the CODE for SIGKILL, that is good because i call kill() in the handler.

Comment: Just to be clear, that happens for you with the program *as presented in the current version of your question*?  I do not reproduce that behavior here, and there isn't much "stuff" done by the children in that version.  None of the stuff that is done looks likely to cause a segfault, except possibly if the `shmat()` in `invite_sent_check()` fails (which you don't check).

Comment: @JohnBollinger There isn't stuff done by children because I get that error message even with that little piece of code everytime I run it. I'm using VirtualBox with Ubuntu 18.04LTS mounted on by iso. A friend of mine with the same Ubuntu's version installed on his HD SOMETIMES he gets the error.

Comment: Your `TEST_ERROR` macro incorrectly assumes `errno` will be zero after a successful function call.  `errno` is only set by failed functions that are documented to set it upon failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been unable to reproduce the segfault locally, and Valgrind does not detect any invalid memory accesses.  There are other possible causes for a segfault, but they are uncommon.  Not being able to reproduce the issue locally, I cannot be confident about identifying its source, but there are a number of issues in the code, mostly minor.

The only issue that seems to have scope to be related to your problem is your redundant attachment of the shared memory segment in function `invite_sent_check()`, especially in view of the fact that you use the return value of `shmat()` without checking it (`(void*)-1` is returned on failure).  Redundant attachments such as that are explicitly allowed, but it would be cleaner and more efficient for the caller to just pass its existing pointer to the original attachment point of the segment.  Moreover, ***if you form a local attachment in that function, then you must be certain to detach again before the function returns***.  Failing to do so could plausibly be the source of the problem, as the metadata and address-space reservations for the resulting many, many attachments could exhaust available resources.

---

Other issues include

- `dprintf()` is not async-signal-safe, but is called from a signal handler (both explicitly and via macro `TEST_ERROR`).
- `shmat()` is not async-signal-safe, but it is called from a signal handler.  Moreover, this seems unnecessary, because the new segment attachment is not used in the handler.  Furthermore, it is not detached, either.
- `semctl()` is not async-signal-safe, but it is called from a signal handler.
- `exit()` is not async-signal-safe, but it is called from a signal handler.  You may use `_Exit()` or `_exit()` instead, but it seems off that this handler should exit the program at all, since the main process seems to have other work that it wants to do to clean up.
- Considering all the things you seem to want to do when you receive the `SIGALRM`, many of them not async-signal-safe, you should consider using `sigsupend()` to receive the signal synchronously, and afterward calling a regular function to do that work.  If you go that direction, then the safest, most reliable approach would involve first *blocking* `SIGALRM` before stting your alarm, then passing a signal mask to `sigsuspend()` that allows that signal.  That will prevent any chance of the signal being delivered before the process is ready for it.
- Function `init()` redundantly attaches the shared memory segment.  This is allowed, but it would be better form for the caller to just pass a pointer to the `struct shared_data` that is to be initialized.  This function, too, fails to detach.
- If you want to check for errors by examining `errno`, you must be certain to set it to 0 before the call you want to check (and test it immediately after, before doing anything else).  However, it is better practice to use functions' return values to detect whether an error has occurred, and to rely on `errno` only to discern *which one*.
- The name and signature of function `maxMin_rand()` suggest it is intended to return a number between `max` and `min`, but it looks like it can return a number as large as `max + min`.

Comment: you are my master. I detached every pointer with `shmdt(corso)` in every function and now the error seems to be gone. Even if I got no return in my function I have to `shmdt(*pointer)` before method ends, right?

Comment: You can view it like `malloc` and `free`: every `shmat()` should be paired with a (exactly one) corresponding `shmdt()`.  This is in fact a pretty good analogy because the reason is the same: avoiding resource leaks.

Comment: Ok now I understand. So in the `main` where should I put the `shmdt` command? Right before `while (shmctl(mem_Id, IPC_RMID, NULL)) { TEST_ERROR; }`? Because I'm deallocating the Shared Memory with `shmctl(mem_Id, IPC_RMID, NULL)` so I detach the pointer before that, right?

Comment: That would work, @Reverendo, but it is ok to mark a shared-memory segment for deletion while it is attached.  The segment persists as long as it is attached to any process.  Your `main` may detach the segment at any point after it is no longer needed, so I think that would be anywhere after the `fork()` loop.  Or, again like `malloc`-ed memory, a process's shared-memory segment attachments are automatically detached when the process terminates.  It is cleanest to detach them explicitly, but it should not present an issue if your `main()` (only) relies on implicit detachment at termination.